# Find outliers without loading big data

Tags: bigdata, bioinformatics, pca, outliers

I am working with a big gene expression data set R. I am not able to load all the data and do the principal component analysis to find the outliers. Is there anyway to find the outliers (or do pca) without loading the data?

Comment: Terms to try searching: "online PCA" "streaming PCA" "incremental PCA". The last one is [implemented in scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_incremental_pca.html), but unfortunately the example doesn't illustrate directly how to stream the data from disk.  However, that should get you started.

Comment: Cool, just found [a similar](https://rdrr.io/cran/onlinePCA/man/incRpca.html) package in R. Thanks!